# Cors issue in HttpResponse Activity

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors, elsa-workflows

I'm running the [Elsa-Core](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core) - AspnetCore Monolith Dashboard sample.

Workflow:,

[image]

This problem happens in the HttpReponse Activity, the HttpEndpoint works fine

I'm getting an error on the client which I can't catch in the server, I think the problem happens in:

```
Elsa.Activities.Http -> WriteHttpResponse -> OnExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context)
```

It seems that `response.WriteAsync` fires some background thread that fails at some point but the exception is not caught:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// The headers to send along with the response.
        /// </summary>
        [ActivityProperty(Hint = "Additional headers to write.", UIHint = ActivityPropertyUIHints.Json)]
        public HttpResponseHeaders? ResponseHeaders { get; set; }

        protected override async ValueTask<IActivityExecutionResult> OnExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context)
        {
    
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext ?? new DefaultHttpContext();
            var response = httpContext.Response;

          ...

            var bodyText = Content;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bodyText))
            {
                try
                {
                    
                    await response.WriteAsync(bodyText, context.CancellationToken); 
                  
                    await Task.Delay(5000);      <--CLIENT FAILS HERE
                    Console.WriteLine("Delay End");
                  
                   
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    var z = ex;
                }
            }
           
            return Done();
        }
```

The API function has not returned when the client already fails:

[image]

[image]

Client only says "Unknown Backend Error, Status = 0"

The workflow instances are created and Finished OK

[image]

This doesn't happen if the call is made from the browser, so it has to be CORS related

I'm using Angular 10, tried in a clean empty project, no credentials, no extra headers in the http call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to update your `Startup` class to:

1. Add CORS services, and
2. Add CORS middleware.

As [you already figured out](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/issues/1039#issuecomment-848754017), make sure to add the CORS middleware component *before* the call to `app.UseHttpActivities()` (which is the middleware handling HTTP workflow requests).

Sample code in `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
// Allow arbitrary client browser apps to access the API for demo purposes only.
// In a production environment, make sure to allow only origins you trust.
services.AddCors(cors => cors.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")));
```

Sample code in `Configure`:

```cs
app
    .UseCors()
    .UseHttpActivities()
    .UseRouting()
    .UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

With that in place, your AJAX calls from your Angular application should now be allowed.